# How to retrieve value of variable in one view from another view in yii

Tags: php, yii, yii-components

I have a variable in admin.php .i.e `$approved`. This is got by the value of a radiobutton using this code.

```
$approval = Yii::app()->request->getParam('approval',"0");
```

Now, I need to pass this variable from admin page to update page. For which I have written the following lines

```
array(
            'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
                        'template'=>'{update}',
                        'buttons' => array(
                    'view' => array (                    
                        'url' => 'Yii::app()->controller->createUrl("/testSettings/update", array("id"=>$data->Id,"approval"->$approval))',
                    ),
                ),
```

I'm not able to retrieve the value of $approved in _form.php.
But, when I gave echo $approved,PHP notice is displayed saying `$approved not defined`but actual value of $approval should be 1. What does this mean and how can I solve this.

Comment: it is $approval not $approved;

Comment: `'url' => 'Yii::app()->controller->createUrl("/testSettings/update", array("id"=>$data->Id,"approval"->$approval))'` Is just plain text value. Remove the `''` around `Yii::app() ....` to execute it.

Comment: @AmazingDreams It is resulting in syntax error.

Comment: @Gopesh Sorry, it is typo error.

Comment: @Gopesh No...can you guide me on this

Comment: Check your code: `"approval"->$approval` ==> `"approval" => $approval`

Comment: What have you passed as a dataprovider to Cgridview ??

Comment: @Ninad $model->search()

Comment: @AmazingDreams "approval" => $approval

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**

You can pass that value to _form as shown

```
$this->renderPartial('_form',array('approval'=>$approval);
```

You can pass as a value param as shown

```
'columns'=>array(
      array(
          'name'=>'yorName',
          'value'=>function($data, $row) use ($controller){
                return $controller->renderPartial('_form', array('approved'=>$approved), true);
          }
      )
  ),
```

Comment: I can get teh value of $approved in admin.php. But, when I pass it to another view file it is undefined

Comment: 'url' => 'Yii::app()->controller->createUrl("/testSettings/update", array("id"=>$data->Id,"approval"=>$approval))', Here $approval value was 0

Comment: Wher is the view file mentioned in it ??

Comment: I need to use $approved value in _form.php. How can I do

Comment: Pls tell me how I can do

Comment: How can I pass from widget in admin.php

Comment: Maybe, you didn't fetch the variable in update.php?
    $approval = Yii::app()->request->getParam('approval');

Or in the controller: public function actionUpdate($id, $approval) (then you need to send it to your view by passing it in your render-function.)

Answer (score 0):

Use `Yii::app()->createUrl` or in the view you can use the controller context with `this` keyword the solution:
in the admin view:

```
array(
            'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
                        'template'=>'{update}',
                        'buttons' => array(
                    'view' => array (                    
                        'url' => 'Yii::app()->createUrl("/testSettings/update", array("id"=>$data->Id,"approval"=>$approval))',
                    ),
                ),
```

in the controller update action you have to pass approval as paramter ($_GET):

```
public function actionUpdate($id,$approval){
    //your code here
}
```